# Datetime expiration next year

Tags: python, datetime

I have a UTCDateTime object in python and I need to check if it is after today but within the next year. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Changed from 13 months to 1 year.

Comment: You would be far better off if you could change the condition from 13 months to some number of days, e.g. 390. This is why you see things like 90 day warranties for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    if now.month < 12:
        expire_date = now.replace(year=now.year + 1, month=now.month + 1)
    else:
        expire_date = now.replace(year=now.year + 2, month=0)
```

although... this will still fail if you run it on, say, January 31st since February 31st doesn't exist.  There are a few conditions you can add related to month dependencies to avoid these problems.

If you changed it to 12 months (re: comment), you only have to worry about leap years.

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
exp_year = now.year + 1
exp_month = now.month
exp_day = now.day

if exp_month == 2 and exp_day == 29:
    exp_month += 1
    exp_day = 1

exp_date = now.replace(year=exp_year, month=exp_month, day=exp_day)
```

Comment: what about something that just checks for a year instead of 13 months?

Comment: then you can remove the condition completely... just go with `exp_date = now.replace(year=now.year + 1)`, though a leap year might still bite you.  You could just check for that.

Comment: How can I use that as a boolean, then?

Comment: `datetime` objects support comparison directly.  You can check if today is earlier than the expiration date by `now < exp_date`

Comment: `if now <= utcdatetime <= expire_date`

Answer (score 1):

The `dateutil` module can handle this for you... (Works same with datetime's as well)

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil import relativedelta

from date import date

d = date(2011, 1, 31)
delta = relativedelta.relativedelta(months=13)
d + delta

#datetime.date(2011, 2, 28)
```

Comment: didn't know about `dateutil` +1 for the best answer and teaching me!